# How do I turn a 3D objects faces outline into a vector?

Tags: vector

I know there is a way to import a vector into blender. I need to do the opposite. Say I have a sphere. I loop cut the sphere, delete half of it and then fill in the face. I want to turn the outline of that face into a vector. I want to do this with a more complex shape obviously. Is there a way to get the exact outline of a face so i can bring it into a program as a vector?

Comment: Blender ships with an 'Export SVG' add-on for Freestyle.. search on 'Export SVG'

Comment: Hello :). Another way that works is to make a UV map projected from view and then export it as .svg.